# Handling listview onItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listView with a search box that searches the listview.I am having a problem assing each item to start different activity because when I search , the position and the id of the items change since the listview will display only the searched result.Can someone help ??

This is my code:

```
        public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {


EditText edittext;
ListView listview;




String[] text = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
"Eight", "Nine", "Ten" };

int[] image = { R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two, R.drawable.three,
R.drawable.four, R.drawable.five, R.drawable.six, R.drawable.seven,
R.drawable.eight, R.drawable.nine, R.drawable.ten };
int textlength = 0;
ArrayList text_sort = new ArrayList();
ArrayList image_sort = new ArrayList();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
listview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(text, image));
listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);






edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
{

}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
int count, int after)
{

}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
int before, int count)
{

textlength = edittext.getText().length();
text_sort.clear();
image_sort.clear();

for(int i=0; i<text.length; i++)
{
if (textlength <= text[i].length())
{
if (edittext.getText().toString().
equalsIgnoreCase((String) text[i].subSequence(0, textlength)))
{
text_sort.add(text[i]);
image_sort.add(image[i]);
}
}
}

listview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter
(text_sort, image_sort));

}
});
}


class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

String[] data_text;
int[] data_image;

MyCustomAdapter()
{

}

MyCustomAdapter(String[] text, int[] image)
{
data_text = text;
data_image = image;
}
MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList text, ArrayList image)
{
data_text = new String[text.size()];
data_image = new int[image.size()];

for(int i=0; i<text.size(); i++)
{
data_text[i] = (String) text.get(i);
data_image[i] = (Integer) image.get(i);
}

}

public int getCount()
{
return data_text.length;
}

public String getItem(int position)
{
return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position)
{
return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View row;

row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);
TextView  textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

textview.setText(data_text[position]);
imageview.setImageResource(data_image[position]);

return (row);

}






}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //HOW SHOULD I HANDLE THE CLICKS HERE 






}
}
```

My Solutions that didn't work :

1) Get the position of the item and go the the corresponding activity

2) Get the id .......................................................

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560273/displaying-results-of-onitemclicklistener-on-a-different-activity/18560308#18560308

Comment: use filter for searching in listview, it will accomodate your search result in the same adapter so there will not be any chance of mistake during onItemClick in listview. Here is the example of custom filter:http://sarath-surisetty.blogspot.in/2012/01/custom-filter-for-custom-listview.html

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,long id) 
{
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityName.this,SecondActivity,class);
i.putExtra("key",position);
startActivity(i)
}
});
```

to Get Value In Second Activity Using Intent

```
int i = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("key");
```

Comment: what does key represent ?

Answer (score 0):

In the getView of the adapter when you are finding any textview you can setTag to that like    `your_text_view.setTag("TextView"+position);`.
After that you can use 
findViewWithTag()method to find exactly which textview or listItem is clicked . For ex:
INSIDE GETVIEW
  `RelativeLayout rel = null;
        if (null == convertView) {

```
        String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
        rel = (RelativeLayout) vi.inflate(resource, rel, true);

    } else {
        rel = (RelativeLayout) convertView;

    }
            rel.setTag("Txt:" + position);`
```

AFTER THAT
`final RelativeLayout rel1 = rel;

```
    // click Listener of day list
    rel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            String seletedPosition = (String) v.getTag();
            String[] splitted = seletedPosition.split(":");
            int tag = Integer.parseInt(splitted[1]);
            mPosition = tag;
            SELECTED_DATE = getItem(tag).date;  
                           if(SELECTED_DATE.equals("something")){
                            startActivity(new Intent(OldActivityContext,NewActivity.class));}`
```

Comment: your code seems applicable in my app , can you show how should I put these lines in the code ? I am a beginner

Comment: all of my code is within the getview of the adapter class.
Also if you wantto acces it outside getView it can be done like :
`rel.findViewWithTag("text:2").setOnclickListener(onclickListener);`
It will give you the relative layout in the second position of your listview.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

EditText edittext;
ListView listview;

String[] text = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten" };

int[] image = { R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two, R.drawable.three, R.drawable.four, R.drawable.five, R.drawable.six, R.drawable.seven, R.drawable.eight, R.drawable.nine, R.drawable.ten };
int textlength = 0;
ArrayList text_sort = new ArrayList();
ArrayList image_sort = new ArrayList();


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    listview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(text, image,prepareIntent()));
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            textlength = edittext.getText().length();
            text_sort.clear();
            image_sort.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
                if (textlength <= text[i].length()) {
                    if (edittext.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String) text[i].subSequence(0, textlength))) {
                        text_sort.add(text[i]);
                        image_sort.add(image[i]);
                    }
                }
            }

            listview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(text_sort, image_sort));

        }
    });
}

private ArrayList<Intent > prepareIntent(){
    ArrayList<Intent> intentList = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("your current activity","you wan to open activity");
        intent.putExtra("key", text[i]);//here you set intent put extra as per your requirement.
        intentList.add(intent);

    }
    return intentList;
}

class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String[] data_text;
    int[] data_image;
    ArrayList<Intent> intentList;

    MyCustomAdapter() {

    }

    MyCustomAdapter(String[] text, int[] image,ArrayList<Intent> intentList) {
        data_text = text;
        data_image = image;
        this.intentList = intentList;
    }

    MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList text, ArrayList image) {
        data_text = new String[text.size()];
        data_image = new int[image.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++) {
            data_text[i] = (String) text.get(i);
            data_image[i] = (Integer) image.get(i);
        }

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data_text.length;
    }

    public String getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row;

        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);
        TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

        textview.setText(data_text[position]);
        imageview.setImageResource(data_image[position]);

        row.setTag(intentList.get(position));
        return (row);

    }

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // HOW SHOULD I HANDLE THE CLICKS HERE
    startActivity((Intent)view.getTag());
}
```

}

Comment: how should I get the extra ? I am a beginner tolerate me

Comment: you get extra on started activity getIntent().get"TypeOfExtra"() method.