# How to pass data from listview to next(details) screen

Tags: android-listview

I have created one sstatic Arraylist and displayed the data in listview using the custom adapter. My requirement is when i click on the listitem, i have to show the details of particular listitem in the next screen. How can i pass the selected listitem data from listview screen to details screen.

I have tried to pass the data using the parcelable concept. But when I click on the listitem, i am getting "Null pointer exception"

Any complete example will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post the relevant part of the code and check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560273/displaying-results-of-onitemclicklistener-on-a-different-activity/18560308#18560308

Answer (score 2):

It can be acheived in following way.I'm assuming that your list item is a text view.

Add onItemClick Listener to your listview,get Selected Item's text on click and pass it with itent extras to NextActivity.

```
  listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View p_view,
                    int p_pos, long arg3) {


                  TextView text= (TextView ) p_view.findViewById(R.id.textview1); //id of textview from layout file that you are inflating.

                  String mytext=text.getText();
                  Intent i = new Intent(Context context,NextActivity.class);
                  i.putExtra("text",mytext);
                  startActivity(i);

                            }
                  });
```

And on the next activity,retreive the text from extras.

```
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            String text_value= extras.getString("text");
```